# Haskell Comparing Sorting Algorithms

Tags: sorting, haskell, iteration

Basically I want to write a function that takes a single list as an input, applies a list of sorting algorithms to that list, and then returns a Boolean indicating whether they all yielded a sorted list or not.

(`checksorted` is a function I wrote that takes a list and returns a Boolean indicating whether it is sorted or not)

This is the code I started with:

```
sortCheck :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool

sortCheck xs = checkSorted(mergeSort xs) && checkSorted(insertionSort xs) && checkSorted(qSort xs)
```

When I try to compile this, I get some sort of type error:
`could not deduce (a ~ Int)`

How could I do this using an infinite list?

EDIT: This is my checksorted algorithm

```
checkSorted :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
checkSorted [] = True
checkSorted [x] = True
checkSorted (x:y:xs) = x <= y && checkSorted (y:xs)
```

Comment: You have to show your `checksorted` function. I have a suspicion that it has a type of `[Int] -> Bool`, not `[a] -> Bool`.

Comment: What are the declarations for the sort functions?

Answer (score 1):

At least one of `checksorted`, `mergesort`, `insertionSort`, or `qsort` must take the type `[Int]` to get that error.

The error message is telling you that you specified that `sortCheck` should work for a list of any type, as long as the type has an `Ord` instance, but the inferred type from the body requires a list of `Int`.

`~` is the type equality constraint.`(a ~ Int)` can be read as "`a` is equal to `Int`".